# How to include an environment variable in a json file?

Tags: json, environment-variables, key

I have some json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "age": 25,
  "profile": "/home/John/Pictures/john.png"
}
```

But i want it to be more general, not specific to John only.
So i want to replace "/home/John" with like $HOME. But that doesn't work with json files apparently. Here's what i tried:

```
{
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "age": 25,
  "profile": "$HOME/Pictures/john.png"
}
```

How can I resolve this? Or is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. It has to do with how you *use* the JSON (after parsing it, at which point, it's not JSON anymore). How are you doing that? What steps are you taking to replace `$HOME` with the appropriate value?

Comment: Simply define the `profile` value to be relative to the user's home directory if it is not an absolute path. But really, you've provided insufficient information to provide a meaningful answer. JSON simply provides a portable way to pass lists of values and dictionaries. It does not have any support for variable substitution. You'll have to do that after parsing the JSON into the equivalent data structures provided by you language (e.g., JavaScript, Python, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

To perform the variable substitution in python3 , follow the below steps.

Change "$HOME" to "${HOME}" in JSON file. The JSON file looks like below:

```
{
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "age": 25,
  "profile": "${HOME}/Pictures/john.png"
}
```

Below script indicates  how to substitute.

```
import os
import json

#Pass the above JSON file and create a file object

fileObj = open('nameOFJsonFile.json',)

#Convert JSON and parse as Python Dictionary

jsonDict = json.load(fileObj)

#Substitute the value wherever required using os.path.expandvars

jsonDict["profile"]=os.path.expandvars(jsonDict["profile"])
```